# Having problem while using shared object in Qtcreator

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I'm trying to use ESNI related method in [this](https://github.com/sftcd/openssl) library. I cloned and install the library using .config && make && sudo make install command. The shared object installed in /usr/local/lib.

First, I checked function that I have to use(SSL_CTX_esni_server_enable) is contained in so file using nm command.

```
pol4bear@pol4bear:~$ nm -D /usr/local/lib/libssl.so | grep -i esni
0000000000026bf0 T SSL_CTX_esni_server_enable
0000000000026aa0 T SSL_CTX_esni_server_flush_keys
0000000000026a60 T SSL_CTX_esni_server_key_status
0000000000028070 T SSL_CTX_get_esni
0000000000028030 T SSL_CTX_set_esni_print_callback
00000000000266a0 T SSL_esni_checknames
0000000000025ce0 T SSL_ESNI_dec
00000000000280d0 T SSL_ESNI_dup
0000000000026720 T SSL_esni_enable
0000000000024800 T SSL_ESNI_enc
0000000000028f80 T SSL_ESNI_ext_free
00000000000293a0 T SSL_ESNI_ext_print
00000000000212e0 T SSL_ESNI_free
0000000000028040 T SSL_ESNI_get_esni
0000000000029570 T SSL_ESNI_grease_me
0000000000021d50 T SSL_ESNI_new_from_buffer
0000000000023080 T SSL_ESNI_print
0000000000028ff0 T SSL_esni_query
0000000000029320 T SSL_ESNI_reduce
00000000000280b0 T SSL_ESNI_set_nonce
00000000000280a0 T SSL_ESNI_set_private
0000000000021880 T SSL_ESNI_wrap_keyshare
0000000000027e90 T SSL_get_esni_status
0000000000028020 T SSL_set_esni_print_callback
```

Second I added library in Qtcreator using "Add Library" and tried to compile code below but it failed with "undefiend reference 'SSL_CTX_esni_server_enable'". How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/esni.h>


using namespace std;

using SSL_CTX_ptr=std::unique_ptr<SSL_CTX, decltype(&SSL_CTX_free)>;

int main()
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method = TLS_method();
    SSL_CTX_ptr ssl(SSL_CTX_new(method), SSL_CTX_free);
    SSL_CTX_esni_server_enable(ssl.get(), "~/esni/hellven1.priv", nullptr);
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Qtcreator .pro file: $$PWD/../openssl/libssl.so and /usr/local/lib/libssl.so are same

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../openssl/ -lssl

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../openssl
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../openssl

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../openssl/ -lcrypto

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../openssl
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../openssl
```

Comment: Can you show the compile command used? Try adding `-Wl,--trace` to see if it is picking up the right `libssl.so`

Comment: Why have you tagged this C?

Comment: I compiled this library using ./config &&  make && make install what libarary's INSTALL says to. Do I have to do make -Wl,--trace to check that libssl.so is ok?

Comment: I removed C tag in this question. Sorry about that if it make you uncomfortable